# PHP: Extract string from another

Tags: php, string

i have some strings (address), all like this:

> 2 rue lambda, 75018, PARIS

I want to get the postal code, in this exemple "75018". I've been trying different solution, but i'm not familiar with escaped characters , and don't know how to detect coma in the string. Which function should i use to extract the postal code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]{5})/',$string,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

This will work whenever there is an address comma separated or simply space separated

Comment: Thanks, this did it (with echo $match[0];), for my problem i think it's the best solution, beacause i'm sure the postal format will always be unique in the string(except for Corse departement whose postal code contain letters). The explode solution could cause problems if someone write he's address like "2, rue lambda...". Thanks everybody

Comment: @joey: yes this will work with any formattation. Please consider to mark this as the answer if this helped you.

Comment: Will probably break on "12345 Whatever, 23456, Fake City".  Make sure your addresses will never have 5-or-more-digit numbers in them.

Answer (score 3):

If all your addresses are of France, which has a 5 digit postal code then you can use the following regex to capture it:

```
\b(\d{5})\b
```

In PHP you can use it with `preg_match` as:

```
$input = '2 rue lambda, 75018, PARIS';
if(preg_match('/\b(\d{5})\b/',$input,$match)) {
   $postal_code = $match[1];
}
```

Note that this will capture the first 5 digit number in the address. *Generally* the postal code comes at the end of the address, so we can improve the method by capturing the *last 5 digit number* in the address by using the regex:

```
.*\b(\d{5})\b
```

Answer (score 3):

If the commas are always there, it is as simple as `explode()`

```
$parts = explode(",", "2 rue lambda, 75018, PARIS");
$postcode = trim($parts[1]);
```

Comment: what if there isn't the comma always there?

Answer (score 0):

Is that always the format it will be in? If so you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$str = '2 rue lambda, 75018, PARIS';
$array = explode(',',$str);
$street = $array[0];
$postal = $array[1];
$city = $array[2];
```